# How to link a folder to create a shortcut

Tags: directory, symlink, cd-command

I have this folder:

```
/var/www/vhosts/foo
```

that I need to access often. If I do (I'm root):

```
ln -s /var/www/vhosts/foo/
cd foo
```

`pwd` tells me `/root/foo`

What can I do to really go into the folder `/var/www/vhosts/foo`. I know that every action on `/root/foo` goes to `/var/www/vhosts/foo`, but what can I do so that `pwd` will tell me `/var/www/vhosts/foo`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `cd -P`  According to the [POSIX spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cd.html),

> -P
>   Handle the operand dot-dot physically; symbolic link components shall be 
>   resolved before dot-dot components are processed (see step 7. in the 
>   DESCRIPTION).